# capistrano deployment to a server without public IP through a proxy

Tags: proxy, capistrano, web-deployment

The server that I need to deploy to is in a private network (without a public IP). I can access the server from outside that network through VPN, but with difficulties, and deployment with capistrano breaks every time.

I have access to another computer in that private network that has a public IP.

Is it possible to set up the capistrano deployment scripts so that the deployment goes through that "proxy" server?

Can you perhaps suggest some other solutions for my situation other than working out the problem with the VPN, which is out of my hands.

Setting up a github hook which would trigger a script on the server that would then pull the branch comes to my mind, but that is much less then what capistrano does: no migrations, revisions, bundle update, server restart, etc...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Capistrano communicates to the target server over SSH - if you setup the SSH connection to proxy through your '[bastion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host)' server and land on the appropriate final host(s), then Capistrano - over that connection - will do the same.

One of the easiest ways of setting this up, is with a ~/.ssh/config block, describing where you want to end up, and the proxy to be able to reach it.

Exactly how that is configured, depends on how you have setup the network.

Here's an (edited for hostnames) .ssh/config file I've just created to SSH from: *home* via *public* and then on to *final*:

```
Host internalvia
    HostName final.hostname.com
    User secretdeployuser
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    ProxyCommand ssh public-server.com -W %h:%p
```

I could then `ssh internalvia`, and land on the machine called final.hostname.com, but I went through public-server.com (logging in first, as myself, and then,of final as 'secretdeployuser'. Both public and final have my usual id_rsa key allowed to login, and the standard forwarding allows me to login to both, even via one another.

When this was working for you to be able to ssh in to the final location from the command line, you can put the `internalvia` as the host in the Capistrano setup.

```
role :app, %w{ secretdeployuser@internalvia }
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks, I will try it out now. It is much simpler then some other solutions that I was considering such as having capistrano on "bastion" and doing deploy from there, or initiating deploy from the private server itself.

Comment: With key forwarding, it may be safer to actually run the deploy from your local machine - that avoids having private keys on remote hosts.

Comment: Great answer. If you are using EC2 with SSHKeys, you may already have a host config setup for the bastion server.  You can replace the public-server.com address with your SSH config hostname.  You can also include `ForwardAgent yes` in both host configs if you want to carry your credentials forward to perform GIT operations or to SSH to another server in the private network.